# How do I get an incremental value after every month and store all previous values in Python

Tags: python, loops, if-statement

I am trying to do a daily update that generates a consecutive number after every month and keep same number if day is still within same month.

For example, starting at day 1 of this month, I got number 1, Day 2->end of this month I still get number 1. However, Day 1 next month, I will get number 2, day 1 the month after next month I get number 3, etc. Also I want to store all of the values and the month name in a list or dictionary.

I have tried an if condition that if today's month is same as yesterday's month then same number, else add 1 to current number. However, I don't know how to store all distinct numbers generated and how to continue as a daily loop.

Please share if you have any ideas, thanks!

Comment: If you don't care about the day you can just use `datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m")` to get a nice number that changes every month and only ever increases.

Answer (score 0):

I think that might be an inelegant solution, I would suggest instead using the python [datetime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html) module. Using this you can check the numerical value of the month (1-12) whenever the script runs.

Something like:

```
from datetime import date

month = int(date.today().strftime("%m"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you don't want the month number but a month counter, i.e. 1 != January.

```
import datetime as dt

month = dt.datetime.now().month
counter = 1
while True:
    new_month = dt.datetime.now().month
    if month != new_month:
        month = new_month
        counter+=1
    print(counter)
```

First, get the current month and store it in `month`, and start a `counter`. The while loop will run forever, so you'll be constantly checking if the month has changed, with the variable `new_month`, when this happens it won't match the original value of `month`, triggering an update on `month`, and adding a one to the `counter`.

The day won't matter as you'd be getting only the month number.

Answer (score 0):

First, should define a list to store the names of the months of the year as strings. Then, you should define a list to store the number of days in each month. Both list should have the months in order. Then you can create an empty list to store your number and month name. You should define a variable that hold 1 to use to append the number associated with the day. First, you should traverse the list of the number of days in a month to access the number of times you should assign a number to a day in a particular month by using a for loop. You can use a nested for loop to repeat the append statement the same amount of times as the value of the number of days in that particular month. Inside the nested loop, you can append the number of the day and the name of the month together by appending a list of the number and the name of the month to the list. The variable number should be equal to the number of the day, and the name of the month can be found by accessing the item in monthsName with an index of number minus one because the index starts at zero not one. When the nested for loop is done, you should increment number to update it for the next iteration. You can output the new list by printing to the console.

```py
monthsName = [“January”, “February”, “March”, “April”, “May”, “June”, “July”, “August”, “September”, “October”, “November”, “December”]
monthsLength = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
numberAndDay = []
number = 1
for num in monthsLength:
    for i in range(0, num):
       numberAndDay.append(number, monthName[number - 1]
    number += 1
print(numberAndDay)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).